# Python Code Not Working!-- Convert array into Zig-Zag fashion

Tags: python-3.x

Given an array arr of distinct elements of size N, the task is to rearrange the elements of the array in a zig-zag fashion so that the converted array should be in the below form:
arr[0] < arr[1]  > arr[2] < arr[3] > arr[4] < . . . . arr[n-2] < arr[n-1] > arr[n].

```
   def zigZag(self,arr, n):
        res=[]
        r=(n//2)+1
        arr.sort()
        j=0
        i=0
        for k in range(0, r, 1):
            res.insert(i, arr[j])
            res.insert(i+1, arr[j+r])
            i= i+2
            j+= j
        return res
```

Comment: `j += j`. If `j` starts out at `0`, it will never change.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the array and add to the new array from both sides of the array.

```py
def zigZag(self, arr, n):
    res=[None]*n
    arr.sort()
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < n//2:
        res[j] = arr[i]
        res[j+1] = arr[n-1-i]
        i+=1
        j+=2 
    if n%2 == 1:
        res[-1] = arr[n//2]
    return res
```